# Migrate Core Data App to iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, icloud

This is my scenario:

My app use core data and i'm adding iCloud support, but i'm having problems trying to migrate users data to iCloud.

Here what i had tried:

**- Added my current local database using addPersistentStoreWithType**

```
    NSError* error;

    NSURL* oldStoreURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:NULL];
    oldStoreURL =[oldStoreURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];

    // add local store (local version)

   NSPersistentStore  *store =  [self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator  addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                        configuration:nil
                                                                                  URL:oldStoreURL
                                                                              options:options
                                                                                error:&error];
```

**- Use the method migratePersistentStore to migrate (probably i'm missing something here):**

```
    NSURL* storeURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:NULL];
    storeURL =  [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];

[self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:store toURL:storeURL options:iCloudOptions withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];
```

I'm getting a Cocoa error 134080, Can't add the same store twice.

Can someone explain how this migratePersistentStore  method works and what i need to pass for each parameter? I found little about it on Apple docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `migratePersistentStore` is that you're moving to a **different** store. You can't migrate to and from the same place.

Since you're migrating to iCloud, use a different name and/or path for the iCloud-enabled store. For example, name the iCloud one `Database-iCloud.sqlite`. Then migrate from your existing store to that one.